# List files with extension matching conditions

Tags: shell, unix, glob

I am trying to list all .mp4 files that start with D and the length of filename should be minimum of 5 in a single command. I don't know how to add the length requirement into the command. This is what i have so far:

```
  ls [D]* | *.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
ls D????*.mp4
```

`?` matches any single character; `*` matches 0 or more of any character. `D????` means "a string starting with D and 4 more characters". This encodes your length requirement.

Comment: i forgot to add to find length of filename excluding .mp4

Answer (score 1):

Use question mark:

```
ls D????*.mp4
```